# How to read JSON.text file to produce data type in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to mock a networking result data and mock it in the JSON.txt, I want to perform unit test of json parsing but it seems that I always failed to read the JSON.txt file

the method that will be tested:

```
class Music {


    func parseJSON(data : Data) -> [[String:Any]]? {

        return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
    }
}
```

and here is the testCase

```
import XCTest
@testable import basicUnitTesting

class musicTests: XCTestCase {


    func testParseJSON() {
        let music = Music()
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        if let path = bundle.path(forResource: "JSON", ofType: "txt") {
            if let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
                let result = music.parseJSON(data: data)

                XCTAssertNotNil(result, "It should not be nil")
                XCTAssertGreaterThan(result!.count, 0, "It should have value, not zero")
            } else {
                XCTFail()
            }

        } else {
            XCTFail()
        }

    }



}
```

and here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

as you can see, the path is nil and then the test failed.

and here is the data inside the JSON.txt to mock the data

> [{"id":"1","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/ModernHardRock_45450.wav","name":"Modern
>   Hard Rock","description":"Powerful rock track with cool guitar riffs,
>   energetic groovy drums, tight bass and guitar solo. Perfect for use in
>   sport (like boxing) videos, advertisements
>   etc.","duration":"2:18","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/ArtistWorking_059730538.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/ArtistWorking_059730538.png","created_by":"ikoliks","file_name_original":"Modern
>   hard
>   rock_LYNDA_45450.wav"},{"id":"2","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/AcousticIntro_45687.wav","name":"Acoustic
>   Intro","description":"Short acoustic guitar intro with a dreamy,
>   relaxed quality that inspires
>   reflection.","duration":"0:57","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/BalletInSmoke_054599628.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/BalletInSmoke_054599628.png","created_by":"Trevor
>   Lackey","file_name_original":"Acoustic
>   Intro_LYNDA_45687.wav"},{"id":"3","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/OptimisticLife_41224.wav","name":"Optimistic
>   Life","description":"Song with optimistic vibe, that's perfect
>   background for music videos that need an uplifting and cool
>   atmosphere.","duration":"0:30","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/BlowingGlass_066874921.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/BlowingGlass_066874921.png","created_by":"PremiumAudio","file_name_original":"Optimistic Life_LYNDA_41224.wav"},{"id":"4","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/TraceyLarvenz_35879.wav","name":"Light
>   and Oxygen","description":"A bubbly, soothing track suited for
>   corporate, marketing, and motivational
>   videos.","duration":"3:05","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/FireDancers_042981315.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/FireDancers_042981315.png","created_by":"Tracey
>   Larvenz","file_name_original":"Tracey Larvenz
>   track_LYNDA_35879.wav"},{"id":"5","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/ExploreCaliforniaIntro_8773.wav","name":"Exploring
>   California","description":"A synth and percussion track as smooth as a
>   drive along the California
>   coast.","duration":"0:20","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/GlassBlownDragon_056473995.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/GlassBlownDragon_056473995.png","created_by":"Bryce
>   Poole","file_name_original":"Explore California
>   Intro_LYNDA_8773.wav"},{"id":"6","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/Aspire_45442.wav","name":"Aspire","description":"\t\rInspiring
>   and beautiful track played by acoustic piano, electric piano, celesta
>   and some light oboe and clarinet sounds in the
>   chorus.","duration":"2:45","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/GraffitiArtist_065000861.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/GraffitiArtist_065000861.png","created_by":"AudioQuattro","file_name_original":"Aspire_LYNDA_45442.wav"},{"id":"7","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/BeginningInTheFarm_41245.wav","name":"Beginning
>   In The Farm","description":"Positive and inspiring. Dreams, ideas, and
>   a sense of something new and full of
>   beauty.","duration":"2:06","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/GraphicArtist_052214820.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/GraphicArtist_052214820.png","created_by":"Julio
>   Kladniew","file_name_original":"Beginning In The
>   Farm_LYNDA_41245.mp3"},{"id":"8","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/BrightAcousticAmbient_35443.wav","name":"Bright
>   Acoustic Ambient","description":"Acoustic guitar and ukulele mellow
>   track with a 12-string acoustic guitar as the main
>   instrument.","duration":"3:21","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/PleinAirArtist_061873487.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/PleinAirArtist_061873487.png","created_by":"Eliosmusic","file_name_original":"Bright acoustic
>   ambient_LYNDA_35443.wav"},{"id":"9","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/BrothersInArms_46815.wav","name":"Brothers
>   In Arms","description":"A themed narrative piece depicting wartime
>   heroes, victorious and fallen. Good for poignant, emotive scenes of
>   loss and
>   tragedy.","duration":"1:15","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/SculptorWelding_053783433.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/SculptorWelding_053783433.png","created_by":"John
>   Leonard French","file_name_original":"Brothers In
>   Arms_LYNDA_46815.wav"},{"id":"10","music_url":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/music/BusinessCorporateBackgrounds_41443.wav","name":"Business
>   Corporate Backgrounds","description":"Positive, uplifting, and
>   inspiring soft corporate ambient music that is perfect as background
>   music for inspirational stories, advertisements, TV commercials, brand
>   company and news, science and invention, architecture and trade,
>   technology and education, and much
>   more.","duration":"2:57","image":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/SpinningPottery_061544433.png","thumb":"http://orangevalleycaa.org/api/media/images/thumbs/SpinningPottery_061544433.png","created_by":"AZOVMUSIC","file_name_original":"Business Corporate Backgrounds_LYNDA_41443.wav"}]

Comment: Is the `txt` file in the test bundle and is the `Target Membership` checked?

Comment: instead of **TEXT** your extension must be **JSON** type. Cheers.

Comment: @dahiya_boy No, it doesn't matter. Actually JSON is plain text.

Comment: @vadian So it is same whether we use JSON or TEXT extension for local json structure file?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. If you are loading `Data` the file extension is irrelevant as long as the URL is valid.

Comment: have you included this file on `Copy Bundle Resources` on `Build phases` tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its clear from the error that your file is not included in resources path
Error line > `if let path = bundle.path(forResource: "JSON", ofType: "txt")`

So, The issue is that your file is not included here **musicTests > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add that JSON to your test target (select JSON file in file navigator, after that at the right panel locate "Target Membership" and verify checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
class Model: NSObject {

    static var jsonDict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

    func readJson() {
        do {
            if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "LinqContents", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let dict = json as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                    Model.jsonDict = dict
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make it worse. A JSON value is never `AnyObject` in Swift 3+